# field < currentdate - 7 format date

Tags: sql, sql-server

My datetime field is in date format M/dd/yyyy. 
SQL Server date is in date format yyyy-mm-dd.
I need to get the current date -7 days and format the output

Example.

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
WHERE Time Generated >= current date - 7 days
```

Output of current date - 7 should be M/dd/yyyy

```
SELECT FORMAT(Getdate(), 'MM dd, yyyy')

DECLARE @date varchar(30) = FORMAT(getdate(), 'M/dd/yyyy');  
SELECT Computer, AppFileDisplayName FROM DHAppReliability
WHERE HasCrashesDaily = 'TRUE'
AND TimeGenerated <= DATEADD(DAY, -7, @date)
ORDER BY Computer
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. Formats apply only when parsing strings into dates, or formatting dates into strings for display. SSMS will *always* use the ISO8601 format because it's the only unambiguous format. That doesn't mean the dates have some specific format

Comment: what data type is field 'Generated'?  when you say your date format is M/dd/yyyy, do you mean it's saved in a string in that format, or that SSMS shows it like that?

Answer (score 1):

Fix your data!  Don't store dates as strings.

In any case, you need to do the comparison using the built-in date/time functionality.  That would be:

```
SELECT Computer, AppFileDisplayName FROM DHAppReliability
WHERE HasCrashesDaily = 'TRUE' AND
      CONVERT(date, TimeGenerated, 101) <= DATEADD(DAY, -7, @date)
ORDER BY Computer
```

I'm not 100% sure that format `101` is the right format, because you have not provided sample data.